Getting the current authenticated user
I am quite new to Apache Shiro and currently developing a Spring Webmvc application with using it.
After a user is logged in: How can I retrieve the logged in user in the Spring controller method at its best?

You can call SecurityUtils.getSubject()
See this related example.
